# Increase in execution time adding unnecessary JARs

Tags: java

Is there any chance that by adding additional jar sites unrelated to a project, this time adding to drop classes running in VM? I was out of the question that this action will increase very little time compiling the overall project.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler used hash based lookup or direct mapped LUT (look up table). Performance will be almost the same for everything (compiling and running), but there will be a small bump in time caused by loading more code. If this is every Java project on GitHub and Google code, then maybe there will be a terrible slow down. I just imagine a project the size of Windows OS or Visual Studio (source) being enough that you should really worry. There will be increased memory usage too, which has some performance impact when you are low in memory.

I should ask whether you are just adding Jar files or source code. In short, Jar and class files will have small impact (negligible). Source code will definitely have a noticeable impact. E.g., including the Apache Commons source instead of using their binaries.